# phonegap build error with google adMob in config

Tags: cordova, admob, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap-admob

my config.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.onsen.helloworld" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Onsen UI Project</name>
    <description>
        Onsen UI project to create fancy user interfaces for hybrid mobile applications. It uses uses Apache Cordova to help you build an app that targets multiple mobile platforms: Android, iOS, Windows, and Windows Phone.
    </description>

    <author email="dev@onsen.io" href="http://onsen.io">
        Onsen UI Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <engine name="android" spec="~4.1.1" />
    <gap:plugin name="com.admob.google" version="2.0.2" source="plugins.cordova.io" />
</widget>
```

When I try to build from build.phonegap.com, I get the following error:

```
plugin source unsupported: com.admob.plugin from plugins.cordova.io
```

What is the wrong with the confic.xml?
Please help

**EDIT**: 
Changing the admob plugin line to this still gives 'malformed confic.xml' error

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-admob" source="npm"/>
```

Comment: you can try this pluign [read more here](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap plugins has been updated to new naming (cordova-...). You need to change the line:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.admob.google" version="2.0.2" source="plugins.cordova.io" />
```

With this other one:

```
<gap:plugin name="phonegap-admob" source="npm"/>
```

See [cordova/phonega admob plugin documentation here](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova)

Comment: Are you using phonegap build or local CLI? In case you are using local cli, you have to add the plugin manually `cordova plugin add cordova-admob` and remove any `<gap:` tag in config.xml

Comment: I am building from build.phonegap.com. @Miquel

Comment: not sure, but could you try to replace single quotes from config.xml? Just in case... Also take a look if there are alt+space spaces (not regular spaces)

Comment: I did that but still getting confic.xml error @Miquel

Comment: I've updated the project, you should use `<gap:plugin name="phonegap-admob" source="npm"/>` (also edited the answer)